# Logic Game Wth Airline Flights

Tags: logic, game-theory

On Saturday eight flights j k l m n o p and r are scheduled to depart from a small airport in Darby Field. For safety reasons, no two flights depart at the same time and each flight depart exactly once The flights depart according to the following conditions: 
Flight R departs some time after L 
Flight K departs some time after flight P but before R 
Flight L departs some time before flights O and J 
Flight M departs some time before flight k and flight N departs some time after flight R 
Flight J is the seventh flight to depart.

1. Each of the following could be forth flight EXCEPT:

a.K

b.R

c.O

d.P

e.M

2. If L is the fourth flight to depart, each of the following could be false EXCEPT:

a. M is the second flight to depart

b. O is the eighth flight to depart

c. N is the sixth flight to depart

d. K is the third flight to depart

e. P is the second flight to depart

3. If flight N departs before flight O, which of the following could be true?

a. Flight R departs sixth

b. Flight K departs third

c. Flight O departs earlier than flight J

d. Flight K departs fifth

e. Flight M departs fourth

4. Which of the following must be true?

a. Flight M departs before flight L

b. Flight P departs before O

c. Flight L departs before N

d. Flight K departs before O

e. Flight L departs before K

5. Which of the following could be the order, for the first to last, in which the flights depart?

a. L, P, M, K, R, N , J, O

b. P, K, R, N, L, O, J, M

c. M, L, P, K, R, O, N, J

d. M, K, P, L, O, R, J, N

e. P, M, K, R, L, N, J, O

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What are your thoughts about this?

Comment: I've actually solved problems 1, 2, and 4. But I'm stumped on 3 and 5.

Answer (score 0):

For 3) note that $N$ can only leave at 6 or 8 and $R$ can only leave at 5 or 6. If $N$ departs before $O$ it departs at 6 and $O$ at $8$, then $R$ has to leave at 5. As $M<K<R$ we find that $K<5$ and $M<4$. $K$ could depart at 3 though, so 3) b.

For 5) we can see that only $N$ and $O$ can depart at 8, so b and c are wrong. Also as mentioned $R>4$ so e is wrong. Also $P<K$ so d is wrong. Leaving a as the only plausible option which indeed does satisfy all conditions. Namely:
$$L<R,\ P<K<R<N,\ L<O,\ L<J\text{ and }M<K.$$